# Sorting a list of objects based on how closely they compare with another object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my user object:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I select the currently logged in user based on their user id:

```
User CurrentUser = Db.Users.Find((int)Session["UserId"]);
```

Next, I select a list of all users except the currently logged in user:

```
List<User> Users = Db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId != CurrentUser.UserId).ToList();
```

Here's where it gets really confusing: I want to sort this list of users based on how closely their lists of tags compare to the currently logged in user's list of tags. For instance, assume User A - who is currently logged in - has the following list of tags:

```
List<Tag> CurrentUserTags = new List<Tag>
{
    new Tag
    {
        TagId = 1
    },
    new Tag
    {
        TagId = 2
    },
    new Tag
    {
        TagId = 3
    }
}
```

User B has tags 1 and 2. User C only has tag 1. I want to sort the list of users as follows: User B then User C, because User B's list of tags compares more closely to User A's list of tags than User C's list.

I really hope this makes sense, as I am completely stuck.

Comment: Tags.Count - the count of current user tags joined to the user tags you are comparing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a hash set with the identities from the tags:

```
var currentTags = new HashSet<int>(CurrentUserTags.Select(t => t.TagId));
```

Then you can count the tags that exist in the hash set:

```
Users = Users.OrderByDescending(
  u => u.Tags.Count(t => currentTags.Contains(t.TagId))
).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't really understand what this is doing, but it's the only solution that didn't give me a compile or run-time error! It seems that the users aren't being ordered though, because whether I use OrderBy() or OrderByDescending() the order is the same.

Comment: Nevermind - it worked. I'm still not sure what's happening but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Begin by using `Intersect`

```
Users.OrderBy(o => o.Tags.Intersect(CurrentUser.Tags).Count)
```

Now this is not going to work because it will be comparing references to Tag objects, where as you want the IDs.

You have a choice of either implementing custom equality operator or a `IEqualityComparer<T>` and passing that.

```
public class TagComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tag>
{
    public bool Equals(Tag a, Tag b)
    {
        return a.TagId == b.TagId;
    }
}

Users.OrderBy(o => o.Tags.Intersect(CurrentUser.Tags, new TagComparer()).Count)
```

Comment: That should be `Users.OrderByDescending(o => o.Tags.Intersect(CurrentUser.Tags, new TagComparer()).Count()) 
`

Comment: @phoog As long as it is sorted according to given criteria, it can always be simply `Reverse()`d.

Comment: Sorting and then reversing is much more expensive than just sorting in the other order to begin with.

Comment: @phoog More expensive? I suppose technically it is. Much more expensive? I would have to see some hard numbers to believe this isn't an unnecessary microoptimization.

Comment: less code, fewer allocations, fewer operations, and easier to understand.  That's not what I usually think of when I think "unnecessary microoptimization"

Comment: @liho1eye, the problem I'm running into with this solution is the Compare() method is of the IComparer<T> class. When I try changing the inheritance from IEqualityComparer<Tag> to IComparer<Tag>, then it has a compiling fit on the line `Users.OrderByDescending(o => o.Tags.Intersect(CurrentUser.Tags, new TagComparer()).Count())`

Comment: @davidkennedy85 You are correct of course. I did confuse the IComparer and IEqualityComparer. See corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting List by a criteria, I usually implement IComparer interface.

```
public class CompareUser : IComparer<User>
{
    public User o;

    public CompareUser(User p)
    {
        o = p;
    }

    public int Compare(User o1, User o2)
    {
        return (o1.Tags.Intersect(o.Tags).Count() < o2.Tags.Intersect(o.Tags).Count()) ?
            1 : -1;            
    }
}
```

then use this Comparer to sort List.

```
CompareUser c = new CompareUser(CurrentUser);
Users.sort(c);
```

HTH.

Comment: This resulted in a run-time error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The problem line is `return (o1.tags.Intersect(o.tags).Count() < o2.tags.Intersect(o.tags).Count()) ? 1 : -1;` Also, since `tag` isn't a property of the User class, I had to change it to `tags`.